# Where does Flutter's attach debugger output to?

Tags: debugging, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-debug, vscode-debugger

- For this experiment, I am using an unmodified default Flutter project which I am testing on a note 9 over usb.
- VS Code version: 1.34.0.
- Dart extension version: 3.1.0.
- Flutter extension version: 3.1.0.
- Flutter doctor output:

```
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Landon
      Blackledge\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional;
      useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android
      Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program
      Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter
      specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart
      specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.34.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.1.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM N960U • 29d9117531047ece • android-arm64 •
      Android 9 (API 28)
```

---

Whenever I enter "flutter run" in terminal, everything runs smoothly, i.e., hot reload & restart work & also logs & prints output to terminal!

The same is true, whenever I click "Start Debugging" on the "Debug" panel; the only differences being that I must use CTRL+F5 & CTRL+SHIFT+F5 (rather than entering "r" & "R" in terminal) for hot reload & restart & also logs & prints output to "DEBUG CONSOLE".

My issue results from changing the default launch.json file from this...

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

to this...

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, whenever I click "Start Debugging", my prints & logs don't show up ANYWHERE! Where could they be outputting to?

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter attach shows output to the DevTools debugger and profiler, you have to open that and provide it with the URL for the running app.